# How to stop slider from animating on hover?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

1.How to pause/stop/continue animating when mouse over/off image?

When my mouse is hovering over my image, i would like for the image to pause while the mouse is hovering over it. Then i would like it to continue scrolling through the images when the mouse is out of image.

```
jQuery(function ($){
    // settings
    var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
    var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
    var $transition_time = 4000; //millseconds
    var $time_between_slides = 1000; //millseconds
    var $stopAnimating = true;
    var timeout;
    function slides() {
        return $slider.find($slide);
    }

    slides().fadeOut();
    // set active classes
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);
    $interval = '';


    // auto scroll 
    $interval = setInterval(function (){
        var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();
        slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
        slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);
        if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start          
        slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
        slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');           
    }, $transition_time + $time_between_slides);

    slides().mouseover(function () {
        slides().stop;
        setInterval = 0;
        alert('mousein');
    });

    slides().mouseout(function () {

        alert('mouseout');
    });



});
```

This is prolly an easy thing to do. but its obvious im a new guy in the field
thanks

Comment: Stop the interval on the `mouseenter` event and restart it on the `mouseleave` event. Search for it if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please describe your problem in more details please. This helps both for answers and for other people having a similar problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [restart image gallery when mouse is not hovering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876436/restart-image-gallery-when-mouse-is-not-hovering)

Answer (score -1):

You are in luck @user2512393 because I already figure it out. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876436/restart-image-gallery-when-mouse-is-not-hovering?rq=1) will help you.

Wrap the interval in a function, declare the interval variable, return the function to the outside and set the hover off to the newly built function.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // settings
    var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
    var $slide = 'img'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
    var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
    var $time_between_slides = 4300; // 4 seconds
    var $interval;

    function slides() {
        return $slider.find($slide);
    }

    slides().fadeOut();

    // set active classes
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

    // auto scroll 
    function startloop(){
    $interval = setInterval(

    function () {
        var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

        slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
        slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

        if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

        slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
        slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }, $transition_time + $time_between_slides);
}
    function pauseLoop() {
        window.clearInterval($interval);
    }

    $(".slider").hover(

    function () {
        //alert("pause");
        pauseLoop(); // pause the loop
    },

    function () {
        //alert("unpause");
          startloop(); //scroll()
    });
    return startloop();
});
```

This code is located on [github](https://github.com/os-pena/Elegant-jQuery-Carousel-Slider) .

Now, I'm trying implement touch detection to pause it on mobile devices.