# restart image gallery when mouse is not hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I restart image gallery when mouse is not hovering over the gallery?  I know I'm close; but, I cannot figure out.  I adapted this [Simple-jQuery-Carousel-Slider](https://github.com/paulmason/Simple-jQuery-Carousel-Slider) of @paulmason at github.

js code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

// settings
var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
var $slide = 'img'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 4300; // 4 seconds

function slides() {
    return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

// auto scroll 
    $interval = setInterval(
      function () {
          var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

          slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
          slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

          if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

          slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
          slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
      }
      , $transition_time + $time_between_slides
    );
function pauseLoop() {
        window.clearInterval($interval);
    }

$(".slider").hover(
    function () {
        //alert("pause");
        pauseLoop(); // pause the loop  | works 
    },
    function () {
        //alert("unpause");
        $interval; //scroll()  here is the problem 
    }
);
});
```

The html is simple.  Just a div with images.

**edit** jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xDf4Z/10

Comment: Please also attach a jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com or codepen.io example of your own code running, so that we can see your code in action.

Comment: here is the link: jsfiddle.net/xDf4Z/10 @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the interval in a function, declare the interval variable, return the function to the outside and set the hover off to the newly built function.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // settings
    var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
    var $slide = 'img'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
    var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
    var $time_between_slides = 4300; // 4 seconds
    var $interval;

    function slides() {
        return $slider.find($slide);
    }

    slides().fadeOut();

    // set active classes
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

    // auto scroll 
    function startloop(){
    $interval = setInterval(

    function () {
        var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

        slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
        slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

        if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

        slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
        slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }, $transition_time + $time_between_slides);
}
    function pauseLoop() {
        window.clearInterval($interval);
    }

    $(".slider").hover(

    function () {
        //alert("pause");
        pauseLoop(); // pause the loop
    },

    function () {
        //alert("unpause");
          startloop(); //scroll()
    });
    return startloop();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xDf4Z/19/